# How To Reset After Unclean Shutdown? Addr in use; no instance of nodeos running

Tags: nodeos, blockchains

Here's how I'm running nodeos:

```
nodeos -e -p eosio --plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin --plugin eosio::history_api_plugin
```

I already tried deleting the "data" folder in `.local/share/eosio/nodeos/`

and tried running it again. It says that the addr is already in use:

```
995027ms thread-0   http_plugin.cpp:338           plugin_startup       ] http service failed to start: Address already in use

995030ms thread-0   main.cpp:133                  main                 ] Address already in use
```

But there's no nodeos process running. In fact, I'm on an AWS and `ps -a` says there's only one process running. So it's gotta be something to do with the data files / config files.

Any ideas on how to complete a full reset of the blockchain?

Comment: What does a `ps -ax` say on the system?  That will list all processes on the box, not just the ones belonging to your account.

Answer (score -1):

I ran command
`ps -ax` which showed a nodeos process running.

I then run 
`pkill nodeos` 
and then deleted `.local/shared/eosio/nodeos/data/blocks` and `.local/shared/eosio/nodeos/data/state`

Which fixed my problem. it.